# Check if a formulation is correct for a set and vertex belong to set

Tags: integer-programming, convex-hulls

Given following set:

$ X =\{x=(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T \in \{0, 1\}^4 : 83x_1 + 61x_2 + 49x_3 + 20x_4 \le 100 \} $

how I can check if:

$ P =\{x \in R^4 : 0 \le x \le (1,1,1,1)^T,$

$ 4x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 \le 4, $

$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 1, $

$ x_1 + x_4 \le 1 \} $

is a formulation for X and all vertex of P belong to X.

I'd like to know how can I proceed, after enumerate the points of $\{0, 1\}^4$ and check if belong to X and P:

x = [0  0   0   1]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

x = [0  0   1   0]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

x = [0  0   1   1]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

x = [0  1   0   0]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

x = [0  1   0   1]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

x = [0  1   1   0]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [0  1   1   1]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  0   0   0]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

x = [1  0   0   1]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  0   1   0]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  0   1   1]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  1   0   0]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  1   0   1]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  1   1   0]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [1  1   1   1]  $\notin X$ & $\notin P$

x = [0  0   0   0]  $\in X$ & $\in P$

I can not figure out, how to proceed, my idea is to find out all the vertex of P but I cannot figure how to proceed.

Futhermore if all vertex of P are integer and belong to X, can I assume that P is conv(X)?

Comment: A good first step might be to enumerate the elements of $X$.

Comment: You have shown that $P$ is a formulation for $X$.  Now enumerate the vertices of $P$.